# Fill variables in MS-Word Document and print it in VB

Tags: vb.net, variables, printing, ms-word

I have a Microsoft-Word document with variables inside it.
These are placeholders (for example name, firstname, date).

My VB program should fill these variables inside the document (For example put date into date variable, name into name variable, and so on) and print the page afterwards.

Is there a way to do that? If yes, what keywords do i have to look up to find the correct commands?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the possibilities Mort mentions, Word also provides

(1) **Document Variables**. These are a string storage inside the Word document that's not visible to nor editable by the user, so are useful for information that should be retained in the document. The content of a Document Variable can be displayed on the document surface by inserting a DocVariable field that references the Variable name. In the object model:

```
ActiveDocument.Variables("name").Value = "text"
```

The basic field code: { DocVariable "name" }

(2) **Custom Document Properties**. These are similar to Document Variables, but can be see and edited by the user in the Document Properties dialog box. The content can be displayed on the document surface using the DocProperty field. Their use in the object model is a bit complexer than for Document Variables as they must be explicitly created:

```
Dim prop As Office.DocumentProperty
Set prop = ActiveDocument.CustomDocumentProperties.Add( _
    Name:="test", LinkToContent:=False, _
    Type:=Office.MsoDocProperties.msoPropertyTypeString, _
    value:="prop value")
Debug.Print prop.value
```

Other differences: A document Variable must have a value and it cannot be an empty string; a custom document property can be an empty string. You cannot "Add" a document property that already exists. The number of characters that can be stored in a document Property is limited to 255.

(3) **Content Controls**. You can think of these a bit like "text boxes" on the document surface. They can also be used with forms protection. If you wish, they can be linked to nodes in a Custom XML Part stored in the document. A content control can be addressed by its position in the document OR by its Title property OR by its Tag property. Multiple content controls can have the same Title and/or Tag property. For this reason, the methods that pick up content controls based on Title or Tag return an array. The code to address a content control:

```
Dim cc as Word.ContentControl, ccs as Word.ContentControls
Set ccs = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitles("name")
Set cc = ccs(1)
```

Which of the five possibilities to use depends on all the circumstances involved in the project, including whether users should set up documents to run with your code, whether the data needs to be extracted from the document at a later point, etc.

Comment: I wasn't able to test it yet, but im pretty sure that (1) is exactly what I've been looking for! Thanks!

Comment: I got one more Question ~ I'm finally on the task which i need this for but i cant find the correct import for (1). Could you help me with that? :-)

Comment: Import? As in an Imports statement at the top of a VB.NET "page"? Imports Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word

Comment: Found that out already, but thanks :-) Should have mentioned i was not making a macro

Comment: Your post was clear enough, I just had my VBA thinking cap on :-)

Answer (score 1):

A possible option is to use Bookmarks in your Word Doc.
Then you parse through the doc and do value substitution like this:

```
doc.Bookmarks.Item(bookmark_name).Range.Text = newValue
```

Alternatively you can search and replace in Ranges like this:

```
Dim doc As Word.Document = Program.LetterInstance.LetterForm.Document
Dim range As Word.Range
range = doc.Content
range.Find.Execute(FindText:=OldText, ReplaceWith:=NewText, Replace:=Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll)
```

Comment: Looks promising. I'll give it a try and response after that!

Comment: I got a new task that I have to do before i can come to this one. And I'll probably rush for Cindy Meisters method (1). Thanks for your help, anyways!